# Tkinter Error: self.tk.call( _tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Below is my draw function written in python using tkinter library:

```
def draw():
global canvas
root.geometry('1080x720')
root.state('zoomed')

# UI_frame1 = Frame(root, width=1000, height=150, bg = 'Blue')
# UI_frame1.grid(row=0,column=0)
canvas = Canvas(root,bg='black',highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

# print(root.winfo_screenwidth(),root.winfo_screenheight())

canvas.create_line(int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.1736),int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.6510),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.1736),fill='white')
canvas.create_line(int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.6510),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0),int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.6510),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*1),fill='white')
canvas.create_line(int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.6510),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.1157),int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*1),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.1157),fill='white')
canvas.create_line(int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.6510),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.8101),int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*1),int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.8101),fill='white')
# canvas.create_line(0,150,1000,150,fill='white')
# canvas.create_line(1000,0,1000,1080,fill='white')
# canvas.create_line(1001,100,1920,100,fill='white')
# canvas.create_line(1001,700,1920,700,fill='white')
UI_frame1 = Frame(canvas,bg='white',width=int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.6510),height=int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.1580)).place(x=int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0),y=int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0))
N = Label(UI_frame1,text='N',bg ='black',fg='white',font=(12))
N.grid(row=0,column=0)
weights = Label(UI_frame1,text='Weights',bg ='black',fg='white',font=(12))
weights.grid(row=0,column=1)
val = Label(UI_frame1,text='Values',bg ='black',fg='white',font=(12))
val.grid(row=0,column=2)
# N = Label(UI_frame1,text='N',fg='white',bg='black',font=(12)).place(x=int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.1067),y=int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.0289))
# weights = Label(UI_frame1,text='Weights',fg='white',bg='black',font=(12)).place(x=int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.2700),y=int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.0289))
# val = Label(UI_frame1,text='Values',fg='white',bg='black',font=(12)).place(x=int(root.winfo_screenwidth()*0.5000),y=int(root.winfo_screenheight()*0.0289))
```

I am getting the error of 'cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack'. I am using pack method to my canvas so that canvas is placed over my entire window. On that canvas I have placed frame using place method. I would like to place my N label to top left side of Frame using grid, but I'm getting the error. I would be grateful if someone could tell me what is wrong with the code.
Thankyou.

Comment: `UI_frame1` is not your Frame, it is actually None (the result of applying `.place()` to the Frame).  Passing None as the parent for the Label makes it a child of the root window, which already has the Canvas packed into it.  You need to split the geometry management into a separate line from the widget creation, at least in cases where you need to assign the widget to a variable for later use.

Comment: Thankyou jasonharper for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is quite a mess... try to remove the unnecessary stuff to help you visualize what you are creating...

A couple of pointers for your consideration:

1. Less can be good. It helps you visualise what you are trying to do.
2. `tk.Canvas` has a `create_window` method to let you position other widgets inside it. Here, I am showing you how to position a `tk.Frame` inside the `tk.Canvas` and then use `grid` method to control the position of the `tk.Label` inside the `tk.Frame` using the grid method. So, you do not need to use the `place` method to position widgets inside a `tk.Canvas`.

Sample script:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('1080x720')
canvas = tk.Canvas(root,bg='black',highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


def draw():
    # 1. Create variable for screenwidth and screenheight
    sw = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    sh = root.winfo_screenheight()
    print(sw,sh)
    
    # 2. Create line borders
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0),int(sh*0.1736),int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.1736),fill='white')
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0),int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*1),fill='white')
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.1157),int(sw*1),int(sh*0.1157),fill='white')
    canvas.create_line(int(sw*0.6510),int(sh*0.8101),int(sw*1),int(sh*0.8101),fill='white')

    # 3. Create Frame widget
    UI_frame1 = tk.Frame(canvas, bg='white', width=int(sw*0.6510), height=int(sh*0.1580))
    # Put Frame inside of canvas using the Canvas's create_window method
    # You can learn more about this method from
    # https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/create_window.html
    canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor=tk.NW, window=UI_frame1)

    # 3. Create Labels and position them inside the Frame widget using the grid method
    N = tk.Label(UI_frame1, text='N', bg ='black', fg='white', font=(12))
    weights = tk.Label(UI_frame1, text='Weights', bg ='black', fg='white', font=(12))
    val = tk.Label(UI_frame1, text='Values', bg ='black', fg='white', font=(12))
    N.grid(row=0,column=0)
    weights.grid(row=0,column=1)
    val.grid(row=0,column=2)

draw()
```

Comment: Thankyou Sun Bear for such long and complete explanation.

Comment: @FahadCharolia Pls accept this answer if you have no issue with it so this question can be recognised as answered. You can ask me if you need more help.